# Ansible ec2_elb_lb HTTPS to HTTP error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have managed to successfully create an ELB using this playbook:

```
 - name: Create VPC network
      ec2_elb_lb:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        name: "ElasticLoadBalancer"
        region: us-east-1
        state: present
        subnets: "{{ Subnet.SubnetId }}"
        listeners:
           - protocol: http
             load_balancer_port: 80
             instance_port: 80
      register: elb
    - debug: msg="{{ elb }}"
```

But I also need to add HTTPS inbound and HTTP outbound, so I added an extra listener as per the [`ec2_elb_lb` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_elb_lb_module.html) example:

```
- name: Create VPC network
      ec2_elb_lb:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        name: "ElasticLoadBalancer"
        region: us-east-1
        state: present
        subnets: "{{ Subnet.SubnetId }}"
        listeners:
           - protocol: http
             load_balancer_port: 80
             instance_port: 80
           - protocol: https
             load_balancer_port: 443
             instance_protocol: http
             instance_port: 80
      register: elb
    - debug: msg="{{ elb }}"
```

After running the above playbook I get the following message:

```
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448959476.82-159664399600608/ec2_elb_lb", line 2519, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448959476.82-159664399600608/ec2_elb_lb", line 693, in main  
    elb_man.ensure_ok()  
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448959476.82-159664399600608/ec2_elb_lb", line 292, in ensure_ok  
    self._create_elb()  
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1448959476.82-159664399600608/ec2_elb_lb", line 397, in _create_elb  
    scheme=self.scheme)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/elb/__init__.py", line 230, in create_load_balancer  
    params['Listeners.member.%d.SSLCertificateId' % i] = listener[4]  
IndexError: tuple index out of range  


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting  

 ansible --version
 ansible 1.9.4
```

Comment: Just ran into this issue, could probably use better exception handling to be fair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to provide HTTPS on the ELB then you need to provide an SSL certificate as well.

So your [`ec2_elb_lb`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_elb_lb_module.html) task should instead look like:

```
- name: Create VPC network
      ec2_elb_lb:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        name: "ElasticLoadBalancer"
        region: us-east-1
        state: present
        subnets: "{{ Subnet.SubnetId }}"
        listeners:
           - protocol: http
             load_balancer_port: 80
             instance_port: 80
           - protocol: https
             load_balancer_port: 443
             instance_protocol: http
             instance_port: 80
             ssl_certificate_id: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/company/servercerts/ProdServerCert"
      register: elb
    - debug: msg="{{ elb }}"
```